# When sending requests in a loop, httpclient starts to be slowing

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have a program that sends a request and parse the response. I want to do 1000 of requests. After 10-15 requests, Httpclient starts to be slowig, and sends a request for about 10 seconds slower, and then slower and slower. Sample code:

```
class a5
{
    public static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task main()
    {
        for (int page = 0; Position < 1000; page++)
        {
            //int totalpages = await frist1(link);
            string full_json = await post_all_pages(page, link);
            var jsons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json5>(full_json);
            // Далее парсинг данных...
        }
    }
    // запрос 
    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> post_all_pages(int page, string link)
    {
        var Other_Link = link.Substring(link.LastIndexOf("/") + 1, link.Length - (link.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));

        var jsonrequest = "{\"PageSize\":" + 25 + ",\"PageNumber\":" + page + ",\"OrderBy\":\"PriceAsc\",\"HotelId\":null}";
        var content = new StringContent(jsonrequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var html = await client.PostAsync("https://intourist.ru/search/api/TourSearch/" + Other_Link, content);
        Console.WriteLine("{\"PageSize\":" + 25 + ",\"PageNumber\":" + page + ",\"OrderBy\":\"PriceAsc\",\"HotelId\":null}");
        Console.WriteLine(html);
        return html.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a question. It is not clear what you want to ask.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I refreshed my question

Comment: `await` on the last line instead of calling `.Result`

Comment: @Artur It didn't help, the problem is the same

Comment: You should not await in the loop. Instead, you should store the Tasks returned by post_all_pages then call Task.AwaitAll

Comment: @Tarik Can you show me example in my code?I don't quite understand what should I do

Comment: are you sure that it's not the server slowing down? Also, you shouldn't create a 1000 tasks and do `AwaitAll` on them, this will be super slow.

Comment: Well, .net manages the execution of the tasks as per the size of the threadpool. Since it is not CPU bound, you may want to have say...50 threads in the threadpool. Most will be waiting for a response from the web site.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool

Comment: Convert the list to array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Task<string>> alltasks = new List<Task<string>>();

for (int page = 0; Position < 1000; page++)
{
    //int totalpages = await frist1(link);
    Task<String> t =  post_all_pages(page, link);
    alltasks.add(t);
    //var jsons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Json5>(full_json);
    // Далее парсинг данных...
}

Tasks.WaitAll(alltasks.ToArray());
```

You may want to create a async function that will calls `post_all_pages`, then await result and then does a `JsonDeserialize`.

[EDIT 07/18/2020]
Using WhenAll is a better solution:

```
await Task.WhenAll(alltasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: I'd say sending 1000 parallel requests to the same server is potentially a good way to either be banned by that server, or, if it's not a huge server, cause it some performance problems. It might be better to batch the requests in, for example, groups of 10 or 20.

Comment: @ADyson You will have as many requests as you have threads in the threadpool. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool

Comment: if post_all_pages return task, how can i give Jsonconverter json data from request?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_ServicePointManager_DefaultConnectionLimit

Comment: You need a function called post_and_deserialize that will do everything. It can call post_all_pages then federalize JSON. I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: @CihanYakar The threadpool size can be controlled. The 1000 tasks will be queued at once but only so many will be executing concurrently. The default can be overwritten to avoid killing the server.

Comment: @Tarik that's a good point about the thread pool, I had overlooked that.

Comment: @Tarik in "Tasks.WaitAll(alltasks);"I have a warning that "tasks" does not exist

Comment: Is it a warning or an error? Missing declaration?

Comment: The important aspect is the idea. The code is approximate as I am using my mobile.

Comment: @Tarik error, i add photo to question

Comment: See fix with call to ToArray()